Hero Widget Animation Not Working in Scrolled GridView
I am working on a Flutter project where I use a GridView.builder to display an infinite scrolling list of products. Each product uses a Hero widget to enable smooth animations when transitioning to a detailed view of the product. However, I’ve run into the following problem:
Problem:
The Hero animations work perfectly for items at the top of the list.
When I scroll down the list and tap on an item to open it, the Hero animation sometimes doesn’t work. I suspect this happens because the Hero widget’s source or destination widget is not in memory.
I temporarily resolved this by increasing the cacheExtent value (e.g., cacheExtent: 2000.0). This keeps more items in memory, allowing the animations to work. However, this approach increases memory usage significantly, especially with large lists.
Code Example:
Here’s a simplified version of the code:
GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
    mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
  ),
  cacheExtent: 2000.0, // Area to keep items in memory
  itemCount: filteredProducts.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final item = filteredProducts[index];
    return Hero(
      tag: item.id, // Unique tag for the Hero widget
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => DetailPage(item: item),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Image.network(item.imageUrl),
              Text(item.name),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);


Questions:
How can I ensure that the Hero widget animations work only for visible items?
Is there a more memory-efficient way to resolve this issue without relying on large cacheExtent values?
What are some best practices or strategies for dynamically rendering only visible items in a GridView?
Thank you in advance for your help!
What I’ve Tried:
AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin:
I used this mixin to retain widget states, but it didn’t resolve the issue with the Hero animations.
VisibilityDetector:
I tried tracking visible items to manage memory and rendering, but it didn’t fully solve the problem.
